# Active Directory Authentication on Node.js WebSocket

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, authentication, azure

I've created a Node.js WebApp and placed it on Azure. This hosts a Socket.io WebSocket and Website that I want to protect behind a form of authentication. My initial plan was to use ActiveDirectory, but I can't find any information on connecting a WebSocket using that kind of authentication.

Is there a way to use Active Directory or another similar and easy to setup authentication to protect both the website and the WebSocket?

I am planning on connecting to this server-side web app from a local machine using a socket.io-client.

Comment: use html+http to connect to AD, then hand-off to web sockets. you can use a token or something from the html if you want to verify the incoming socket connection above and beyond IP.

Comment: If you are using express, i would recommend passportjs, socket.io, then passport.socketio

Answer (score 0):

I would look for an HTTP-based solution which allows you to interact with the active directory environment.  You can then wire together this integration with your existing WebSocket solution.

This library looks promising: https://github.com/gheeres/node-activedirectory

It also looks like Azure provides a REST API for Active Directory: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/hh974476.aspx

I work at [Stormpath](https://stormpath.com), we also have an Active Directory feature that allows you to connect your Node.JS application to a data store that is synced with Active Directory.  See [Integrating Stormpath with Active Directory and LDAP](http://docs.stormpath.com/guides/ad-ldap/)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

After much consideration on simplicity, I decided to drop the traditional Azure provided ActiveDirectory Authentication all together. (It blocks WebSocket traffic so that I could not do any manual authentication over the sockets)

I instead handle the website authentication myself using [Passport](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport) and whichever authentication I choose [Active Directory](https://github.com/AzureAD/passport-azure-ad), [Facebook](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-facebook), [Google](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-google-oauth), [Twitter](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-twitter), [Github](https://github.com/cfsghost/passport-github).

For the Socket.io authentication, I used [socketio-auth](https://github.com/invisiblejs/socketio-auth) to protect the connections with a custom layer of security and authentication.