# Aunthentication of websocket clients?

Tags: azure-active-directory

Is there a way to authenticate a websocket client in Azure AD? Managed to find several examples for http clients (eg, via AunthenticationHeaderValue), but I havent seen how to do this for websocket clients.

Help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Pedro

Answer (score 0):

Azure Active Directory doesn't allow web socket access, you would have to handle the authentication using HTTP and then hand off to the web socket afterwards to carry on.

Not sure what language you are working in but a solution for Node.js has been posted in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29725395/active-directory-authentication-on-node-js-websocket).